# Oracle naming convention

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

Can some one give me an oracle naming convention. I surf the web. but could not find a good site. I tried to find one from oracle site. but failed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Uhm ... what? Could you give some example of what kind of information you're looking for?

Comment: Do you mean a naming convention for tables/fields/etc. of a database?

Comment: @Joachim I'm looking for schemas, tables, columns naming best practices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see the  link.[Oracle9i](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96531/toc.htm) documentation

Some other links for naming conventions

http://www.gplivna.eu/papers/naming_conventions.htm

http://www.dba-oracle.com/standards_schema_object_names.htm

http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-naming.html

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for something like table naming?

http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-naming.html

Comment: just don't understand what is the intention for casting down vote ... :( add a comment by any means.

Comment: I guess posting a simple google link is just not enough.  Maybe not worth a downvote... but OTOH, such an answer doesn't really help.
You'd better comment next time.

Comment: i've specified if this is 'table naming' convention. and a google link is never just a random link, it has my own discretion. to me it is good enough to start the search for the question. i got your point, maybe i will be more verbose and duplicate the info here (which i understand is SO encouraged), maybe i will just skip, anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Looking for the same, I found this Oracle's naming convention for DB objects... which imo doesn't really help :
**https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18727_01/doc.121/e12897/T302934T458266.htm#4164876**

Google will give you many other other.  Here are a few examples :

http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/oracle/w/wiki/4844.variables-best-practices-naming-conventions#establish-clear-variable-naming-conventions

https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/naming-conventions

http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-naming.html

Personally, the most important thing *from my pov* is to have a correct case consistency.

Either you spell all your `SQL KEYWORDS IN CAPITALS` and your `business_vocabulary` with `lower_case`, or the opposite, but avoid mixing both : it just makes everything less readable.

Then, of course, it's good to adopt some conventions, but I guess they are often subjective choices, and the relevancy of such choices depends on the database's purpose.  Good conventions won't be really necessary for a 10 tables DB :)

Among the examples of conventions I personally use, I prefix views with `v_`, prefix all my PK names with `id_`, and my FK with `fk_`...  also, my PK is always my first column (I now avoid multiple columns PK), and all my FK are placed after it (no FK at end of table).

Keep in mind that these examples are ***my*** personal choices

Comment: Care to explain the downvote ?  I couldn't find any constructive official doc about naming conventions.  They all seem to be unclear and/or very subjective.  I can't get why the 2 other answers (which I upvoted from -1 to 0) would be considered better.